# can't change sprite on an object of dictionary

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I am trying to change sprite of an object of dictionary when i click a key on keyboard. But i can't do that. this my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

public class plantingScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public float plantV = 0f;
    public float coordX = 0f;
    public float coordY = 0f;
    public float koordX = 0f;
    public float koordY = 0f;

    public walkingScript ws = new walkingScript();
    public loadGame loadLand ;
    public GameObject gameObj;
    //public SpriteRenderer spriteObj;
    public Dictionary<string,Tanah> tempTanah = new Dictionary<string, Tanah>();
    public Dictionary<string,GameObject> tempObjTanah = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();


    void Awake(){
        //spriteObj = gameObj.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        loadLand = GameObject.Find ("loadGameObject").GetComponent<loadGame>();
        tempTanah = loadLand.myTanah;
        tempObjTanah = loadLand.objTanah;

    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.V))
            cekLokasi();
    }

    void cekLokasi(){
        Debug.Log ("V pressed!");

        GameObject temp = null;

        coordX = (int)(gameObject.transform.localPosition.x / 0.8f + gameObject.transform.localPosition.y / 0.4f) / 2;
        coordY = (int)(gameObject.transform.localPosition.y / 0.4f - (gameObject.transform.localPosition.x / 0.8f)) / 2;

        if(ws.hadapAtas == true && ws.hadapKanan == true)
        {
            koordY = (int) coordY;
            koordX = (int) coordX + 1; 
        }
        else if(ws.hadapAtas == false && ws.hadapKanan == true)
        {
            koordY = (int) coordY;
            koordX = (int) coordX - 1; 
        }
        else if(ws.hadapAtas == false && ws.hadapKanan == false)
        {
            koordY = (int) coordY + 1;
            koordX = (int) coordX; 
        }
        else if(ws.hadapAtas == true && ws.hadapKanan == false)
        {
            koordY = (int) coordY + 1;
            koordX = (int) coordX; 
        }

        if(tempObjTanah.TryGetValue("land-"+koordY.ToString("0#")+"-"+koordX.ToString("0#"),out temp))
        {
            Sprite mySprite = null;
            Debug.Log ("Land found!");
            mySprite = loadLand.myTanah["land-"+koordY.ToString("0#")+"-"+koordX.ToString("0#")].spriteTanah["Garap"];
            Debug.Log ("Sprite found!");

            gameObj = tempObjTanah["land-"+koordY.ToString("0#")+"-"+koordX.ToString("0#")];
            gameObj.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            gameObj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = mySprite;


            /*
            Sprite mySprite = null;
            Debug.Log ("Land found!");
            mySprite = loadLand.myTanah["land-"+koordY.ToString("0#")+"-"+koordX.ToString("0#")].spriteTanah["Garap"];
            Debug.Log ("Sprite found!");
            tempObjTanah["land-"+koordY.ToString("0#")+"-"+koordX.ToString("0#")].AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            SpriteRenderer mySpriteRend = tempObjTanah["land-"+koordY.ToString("0#")+"-"+koordX.ToString("0#")].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            mySpriteRend.sprite = mySprite;
            }
            */
        }
    }
}
```

this is how that dictionary of gameObject was made

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;


public class loadGame : MonoBehaviour {
    public static loadGame loadSave;

    public GameObject objPrince;
    public Pangeran charPrince;
    public Transform prefPrince;

    public Sprite[] spriteTanah;
    public Dictionary<string, Tanah> myTanah = new Dictionary<string, Tanah>();
    public Dictionary<string, GameObject>objTanah = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();
    public Tanah tempTanah;
    public GameObject tempObjTanah;
    public Transform prefTanah;
    public float mapX;
    public float mapY;
    public int i = 0;
    public int j = 0;
    public int rows = 9;
    public int column = 9;


    void Awake(){
        if(loadSave == null)
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            loadSave = this;
        }
        else if(loadSave != this)
            Destroy(gameObject);

    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Load ();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void Load(){
        if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat"))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            charPrince = new Pangeran ("Prince", "04Okt1993", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false);
            objPrince = GameObject.Instantiate (prefPrince, new Vector3 (0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            //objPrince.name = "Prince";
            charPrince.locationY = 0f;
            charPrince.locationX = 0f;
            charPrince.hadapAtas = false;
            charPrince.hadapKanan = true;
            charPrince.stamina = 100f;
            charPrince.exp = 0f;
            charPrince.speed = 0f;

            for(i = 0 ; i < rows ; i ++)
            {
                for(j = 0; j<column ; j++)
                {
                    mapX = (i-j) * 0.8f;
                    mapY = (i+j) * 0.4f;

                    if(i>=1 && j>=1 && i<=5 && j<=5)
                    {
                        prefTanah.name = "land-"+j.ToString("0#")+"-"+i.ToString("0#");
                        tempTanah = new Tanah("land-"+j.ToString("0#")+"-"+i.ToString("0#"),mapX,mapY,"land",spriteTanah[0],spriteTanah[1],spriteTanah[2]);
                        myTanah.Add("land-"+j.ToString("0#")+"-"+i.ToString("0#"),tempTanah);
                        tempObjTanah = GameObject.Instantiate(prefTanah, new Vector3(mapX,mapY,0),Quaternion.identity)as GameObject;
                        objTanah.Add("land-"+j.ToString("0#")+"-"+i.ToString("0#"),tempObjTanah);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        prefTanah.name = "snow-"+j.ToString("0#")+"-"+i.ToString("0#");
                        tempTanah = new Tanah("snow-"+j.ToString("0#")+"-"+i.ToString("0#"),mapX,mapY,"snow");
                        myTanah.Add("snow-"+j.ToString("0#")+"-"+i.ToString("0#"),tempTanah);
                        tempObjTanah = GameObject.Instantiate(prefTanah, new Vector3(mapX,mapY,0),Quaternion.identity)as GameObject;
                        objTanah.Add("snow-"+j.ToString("0#")+"-"+i.ToString("0#"),tempObjTanah);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

and it made an error that said

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object plantingScript.cekLokasi () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/plantingScript.cs:78)

line 78 is

```
tempObjTanah["land-"+koordY.ToString("0#")+"-"+koordX.ToString("0#")].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = mySprite;
```

I am trying to change the sprite with other ways, but i didn't work. 
please Help me. Thank you.

Comment: Just a hint: the way you construct the dictionary keys with ToString is both confusing to write, read and will prove to be inefficient (read: slow) in the long term. The problem you describe is probably the result of using a key that returns a null object, or more simply one of those objects you run ToString on is null.

Comment: i do this to, but i didn't work. the result of that key isn't null. but the spriterenderer does.
`if(tempObjTanah.TryGetValue("land-"+koordY.ToString("0#")+"-"+koordX.ToString("0#"),out temp))
  {
   Sprite mySprite = null;
   Debug.Log ("Land found!");
   mySprite = loadLand.myTanah["land-"+koordY.ToString("0#")+"-"+koordX.ToString("0#")].spriteTanah["Garap"];
   Debug.Log ("Sprite found!");

   gameObj = tempObjTanah["land-"+koordY.ToString("0#")+"-"+koordX.ToString("0#")];
   gameObj.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
   gameObj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = mySprite;
}`

Comment: And just to be clear, `gameObj` is *not null*? If you put a `Debug.Log(gameObj)` in there, the log shows something that isn't null. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

If Unity says it doesn't have a `SpriteRenderer`, then it doesn't have a `SpriteRenderer`.

`gameObj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>()` is what's null, and when you try to access the `sprite` property from it, you get the `NullReferenceException`.

Check how you've created your objects and make sure they have the right components attached. `SpriteRenderer` is not a default component.

EDIT: After reading your new code sample, I have a few more comments but unfortunately not a definite solution to your problem.

Your code is extremely difficult to read and understand, mostly due to the use of common variable names describing different things.

```
prefTanah.name = ...
tempTanah = ...
myTanah.Add(...);
tempObjTanah = ...
objTanah.Add(
```

`prefTanah` is a prefab, but you're changing its name to something that is dynamically generated. This name makes sense, but changing the name like this does not.

Then you create a `Tanah` object which I assume is some kind of data model. Then you add this to a dictionary of `Tanah` objects called `myTanah`.

But you're also maintaining a separate dictionary of `GameObject`s which appear to be related to the `Tanah` objects.

Also, `tempObjTanah` is assigned a `GameObject` in the second code sample, but it is referred to as a dictionary in the first one. Even if these are in different scopes, it's hard to understand for an outside observer.

Unfortunately, I don't see a direct solution to your original problem, but I'm certain that it is a result of your script being very messy and hard to understand. If the prefab referred to by `prefTanah` does indeed have a `SpriteRenderer`, my only guess is that your dictionary does not contain what you think it contains. My advice is to go over your script and make sure it's doing what you think it's doing. You can also try posting the entire script to pastebin or something so we can have more context about what's going on.

Comment: when i instantiate that object from a prefab, the prefab got a sprite renderer. is that mean that the object got spriteRenderer too?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you're instantiating the prefabs and loading them into the dictionary?

Comment: edited my answer. it's hard to get a good idea of what's wrong without more context. you can try posting your entire script for help, or my advice is to go over it again to yourself and make sure it's actually doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: i've edited my question. i added the entire code. Thanks for your help.